# No route calculated when using direction=true

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I am using pgr_dijkstra to calculate routes on OSM data.

When using this call:

```
SELECT *
FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM referentie.ref_osm_edges '
                  ,768576
                  ,537705
          ,false
          ,false ) a
```

I got 10 records like this:

```
0;768576;1351316;0.0288615485
1;768565;1334459;0.00095542657
2;771650;981098;0.0074186646
3;771649;1334458;0.00101160459
4;771651;1022868;0.012433637
5;801545;1022859;0.000870379
6;801544;1022864;0.00048865133
7;801541;1022857;0.0011667417
8;768567;1334465;0.0122069924
9;539063;1366175;0.00064540192
10;537705;-1;0
```

This is OK. 
When using this call (with directed=true):

```
SELECT *
FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM referentie.ref_osm_edges '
                  ,768576
                  ,537705
          ,true
          ,false ) a
```

Then I got no results, also no error just:

Total query runtime: 81 ms.
0 rows retrieved.

So I try to find out why dijkstra cannot find a route based on direction?

Hans

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if you misunderstand the use of `directed`.

As the [pgr_dijkstra documentation](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/dijkstra/doc/index.html#pgr-dijkstra) says you set `directed` to `true` when your graph is [`directed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). It has nothing to do with driving directions.